# how to run build of my expo react native code

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a React Native project by expo. Today I found there was a legacy compiling issue, so I deleted node_modules folder and tried to rebuild it. But when I ran: `npm run build`, it said: Missing script: "build". I also tried `npm build` or `expo build`, neither worked.
My package.json as following:

```
{
  "name": "techpop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    ......
  }
}
```

Mustafa answered my question in comments, the command `npm install` works!

Comment: since you deleted node_modules folder, did you try npm install to reinstall them first?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a build for android

```
expo build:android
```

If you want to create a build for ios

```
expo build:ios
```